# Implement SQL recursive query in both MySQL an SQL Server?

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, hibernate, jpa

I have this native query:

```
 //return all children
@Query(
        value = "WITH cte(uuid) AS" +
                "   (" +
                "       SELECT uuid" +
                "       FROM org_unit " +
                "       WHERE uuid = :uuid" +
                "           UNION ALL" +
                "       SELECT ou.uuid" +
                "       FROM org_unit ou" +
                "       JOIN cte ON ou.parent_org_unit_uuid = cte.uuid" +
                "   )" +
                "  SELECT * FROM org_unit WHERE org_unit.uuid IN   " +
                "     ( SELECT DISTINCT cte.uuid FROM cte)",
        nativeQuery = true)
Collection<OrgUnitEntity> getAllChildrenWithSelf(@Param("uuid") String uuid);
```

but the problem is that this query does not work with MySQL. I want to support SQL Server and MySQL.

Comment: Expecting code to be transferable between RDBMS is little more than a dream I'm afraid. Apart from the most basic of statements, most of the dialects vary at least slightly, and they have different support for different functionality (That varies on the version you are using). If you have T-SQL and want to use it in MysQL, you'll need to write a MySQL version too.

Comment: Perhaps I'm going to try DslQuery. It could help with this problem. I'll let you know.